# How exactly works this header mediator involved in the call of a DSS service call from a WSO2 ESB project?

Tags: wso2, integration, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am absoluty new in **WSO2** and I have the following doubt.

I am working on an **ESB** project. In the  chain there is this **header** mediator

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/glisTest2" name="glisTest2" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET">
        <inSequence>
            <!-- Create empty message to get all samples from DSS -->
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                <format>
                    <body/>
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('uri.var.int_val')" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>

            <!-- 
                 Adding an header that defines the action related to the "FindNotProcessed" DSS service
                 used to retrieve all the unprocessed resource on the DB. 
             -->
            <header name="Action" scope="default" value="urn:FindNotProcessed"/>

               ...................................................................
               ...................................................................
               ...................................................................
        </inSequence>
```

So as you can see the **header** mediator is chained after a **payloadFactory** mediator building an empty message that have to be send to a **DSS** service.

The **header** mediator:

```
<header name="Action" scope="default" value="urn:FindNotProcessed"/>
```

add an header that specify the **operation name** that have to be called on the **DSS** service, this operation infact is named **FindNotProcessed** and it is associated to a defined query.

Ok my doubts are:

1) the value of the **value** attribute specify the name of the operation that have to be performed on the **DSS** service, in this case this value is **urn:FindNotProcessed**.

What exactly means the **urn:** prefix that is putted before the name of the operation to execute?

2) The **header** mediator definition contains also this attribute **name="Action"**.

What exactly represent? Is it something like the mediator name or the value have to be setted on **Action** for some semantic meaning? Is it only a name or exists a set of possible values for this field having semantic behavior?

3) So to call a **DSS** service the propper way is: create a message with a **payloadFactory** mediator, chained it with an **header** mediator that specify the name of the operation that have to be performed on the **DSS** service and then chain a **callout** mediator that perform the call. I have done in this way and works, is it the standard way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **urn:FindNotProcessed** is the SOAPAction name, which is defined in the web service WSDL. **urn:** is just part of that name, it looks like a namespace but it is not.

2)By setting **name="Action"** you are telling which HTTP header you are setting. In this case it will set *SOAPAction: urn:FindNotProcessed*.

3) Exactly, but you can use not only **Callout**, but **Send** and **Call** mediators also, depending of your logic.